# Need HTML code for menu function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, drop-down-menu, menu

I have found the following jquery code for an drop-down-menu.
What should the HTML code contain to work with it?

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){

  jQuery("html").bind("click", function (e) {
    jQuery('.dropdown-toggle, a.menu').parent("li").removeClass("open");
  });

  jQuery(".dropdown-toggle, a.menu").click(function(e) {

    //  First look an see if a menu is open.  If it is, then just close it.
    if (jQuery(this).parent("li").hasClass("open")) {
        jQuery("ul").find('li').removeClass('open');
    }

    //  If menu was not open, then close any other menus that were open and just open the one.
    else {
        jQuery("ul").find('li').removeClass('open');
        jQuery(this).parent("li").addClass('open');
    }
    return false;
  });

});
```

Comment: post what have you tried up to now.

Comment: This is written to work with a specific set of HTML. Are you certain that the place where you got this code did not have the HTML as well?

Comment: Where did you find the code? You'll probably find information about the HTML there.

Comment: @FelixKling This seems to be the twitter bootstrap code.

Comment: @Praveen: I don't see anything Bootstrap specific here... if it was, you would not have to set up any JavaScript, because `data-toggle="dropdown"` would take care of it. Or you would use `$('.dropdown-toggle').dropdown()`... but why this custom code?

Comment: The `.dropdown-toggle` class, and toggling `open` class makes me feel it is bootstrap! `:)` Or may be a cheap remake of bootstrap. What say?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### You need this HTML:

```
<div class="dropdown">
  <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Dropdown trigger</a>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dLabel">
    ...
  </ul>
</div>
```

Or, another method:

```
<div class="dropdown">
  <a class="dropdown-toggle" id="dLabel" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" data-target="#" href="/page.html">
    Dropdown
    <b class="caret"></b>
  </a>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dLabel">
    ...
  </ul>
</div>
```

Inside the `<UL>`, you need to give this way:

```
<ul id="menu1" class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="drop4">
  <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
  <li class="divider"></li>
  <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
</ul>
```

If you want to give a divider, you can give this way:

```
<li class="divider"></li>
```

If you wanna invoke it by JavaScript, you can use this code:

```
$('.dropdown-toggle').dropdown()
```

And it displays this way:

[image: Screenshot]

#### It is [Twitter Bootstrap](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/)'s JavaScript DropDown menu plugin. You can know more about it [here](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#dropdowns).

Answer (score 0):

You should create your own HTML and js code for your particular situtation, not just use a jquery code and guess what the markup should be. There's plenty of tutorials on the web : http://www.google.com/search?q=tuto+menu+jquery&aq=0&oq=tuto+menu+jquery